# Tinfoleak 1.5: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'secure'

Tags: ubuntu, python

I found a Tinfoleak fork on a developer blog (http://www.vicenteaguileradiaz.com/tools/) and tried to use this tool on my own Twitter account, but even after installing any of the required dependencies my Python environment still returns an error. What does this error mean?

```
python tinfoleak.py -h
```

Output:

```
Oops! Something went wrong:

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'secure'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like I've fixed it. I opened tinfoleak.py and removed an argument from the Tweepy API constructor call. My Tweepy version was too new for Tinfoleak 1.5 I guess.

[source-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3AgD.png)